# SQL - char field with date - how to search between two dates

Tags: mysql, sql, date, char, sql-convert

I have simple problem with SQL query.. I would like to search fields, where dates begin and ends in specific date and time.

Field is defined as CHAR and have structure: DD.MM.YYYY hh:mm:ss and I cannot change it.

I tried to declare some variables and search by this, also tried by Converting.

This is what I tried and didn't work:

```
SELECT date FROM table WHERE date BETWEEN '1.01.2017 00:00:00' AND '1.02.2017 23:59:59'

SELECT date FROM table WHERE date >= '1.01.2017 00:00:00' AND date <= '1.02.2017 00:00:00'

SELECT date FROM table WHERE date >= Convert(DATETIME, '1.01.2017', 104) AND date <= Convert(DATETIME, '1.02.2017', 104)
```

Always after this query I get all dates, not this what I asked.

Comment: Your 3rd query is almost correct, you just have to cast the date column to `datetime` datatype.

Comment: What is `104` in the last query? The arguments to `CONVERT` are `(expression, type)`.

Comment: Store dates as dates

Comment: @Barmar If you asking about 104... I found this query with meaning: `Convert(datetime, 'date', style)`.

Comment: @Frihu Are you sure you found it in a page about MySQL? I suspect that's for a different RDBMS.

Comment: @Frihu That's SQL-Server, not MySQL. When you google, make sure you check what database is being explained.

Comment: @Barmar ahh okay, nevermind. So for MySQL correct convert structure is `(expression, type)`  ?

Comment: Yes. Do you know how to read MySQL documentation? https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/date-and-time-functions.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. Problem was with that HOW this fields are storage in DB. 
I thought that they are storage like: DD.MM.YYYY hh:mm:ss, but it was only structure. In DB they are storage like: YYYYMMDDhhmmss and after changes in WHERE query line it works.

```
SELECT date FROM table WHERE date >= '20170101000000' AND date <= '20170101235959'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your field is not in a format that can be compared lexicographically as strings, so you need to convert it to a date. But it's not in the format that MySQL can parse by default (it expects dates in the format `YYYY-MM-DD`). So use `STR_TO_DATE()` to parse it with a format string.

```
SELECT date
FROM table
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%i:%s') BETWEEN '2017-01-01 00:00' AND '2017-01-02 23:59:59'
```

Comment: Yes.Move the piano to the stool

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT date FROM table WHERE STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%i:%s') BETWEEN '2017-01-01 00:00:00' AND '2017-02-01 23:59:59'
```

***OR***

You can use `STR_TO_DATE()` function.

```
SELECT date FROM table WHERE STR_TO_DATE(date, '%d.%m.%Y %H:%i:%s') BETWEEN STR_TO_DATE('1.01.2017 00:00:00','%d.%m.%Y %H:%i:%s') AND STR_TO_DATE('1.02.2017 23:59:59','%d.%m.%Y %H:%i:%s')
```

You can try above query.

Comment: `date` is not a `DATETIME`, it's a `CHAR`, so this will perform string comparison, not date comparison.

Comment: The dv is just for saying the same thing twice

Comment: @Strawberry I had answered 31 min ago and he had 30 min.

Comment: As in repeating yourself

Comment: Where did i repeat?

Comment: Thank you, but it doesn't help me.. After this all query which you posted, I get error and nothing show. I can say also that `char` has defined lenght, its 14 digit, maybe is it matters?

Comment: And... Maybe it is also important, I would like to show this char as the same which are defined in table. e.g. Char in table: 1.01.2017 12:41:23 and OUTPUT same as date and structure: 1.01.2017 12:41:23